# Where is script like wordcount executed in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am asking for knowledge? When running a MapReduce with a wordcount jar when does the code execute? Is it during the mapper task or the driver method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > When running a MapReduce with a wordcount jar when does the code execute?
> >     It executes with main i.e. Driver code and then map code followed by reducer code (if any)
> >
> > Is it during the mapper task or the driver method?
> >     Yes its both.

**Driver** - would drive the map reduce, where you define which class i should use for mapper, reducer, paritioner, combiner.

**Mapper** - mapper is where your word count would create a map of key value pair with key as word and value as number of times it occured.

**Reducer** - Reducer would take the value from each mapper and would sum all the value against same key accross mapper and would give you the final result.

Comment: From what I understand, driver will be like the initial setter of the MapReduce, meaning this will be the first one to execute

Answer (score 1):

as correctly answered by  SMA , code execution starts with main method of driver class ,  which passes control to mapper and reducer class using methods  setMapperClass , setReducerClass  of job object.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at official [map reduce tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) for better understanding. I am using key points to explain the example.

Let's have a look at java word count example.

1. Assume that you have created wc.jar as follows.

   ```
   $ jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
   ```
2. Now run the WordCount example

   ```
   $ bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/joe/wordcount/input /user/joe/wordcount/output
   ```

   Now you have passed input directory & output directory for reading and writing of data respectively.

Assuming that:

```
/user/joe/wordcount/input - input directory in HDFS
/user/joe/wordcount/output - output directory in HDFS
```

**input directory in HDFS is used by Mapper to read the data & output directory in HDFS is used by reducer to store data.**

Applications typically implement the `Mapper` and `Reducer` interfaces to provide the map and reduce methods. These form the core of the job.

If you see the main method of WordCount class (you can call it as `Driver` program),

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

We are setting Mapper class, Reducer class, Combiner class, Output Key & Value classes and Input/Output file locations.

Some jobs may have only Mapper. Some jobs will have Mapper and Reducer. Some jobs will have Partitioner & Combiner in addition to Mapper & Reducer classes. So basically the flow is decided by you and Hadoop framework will form a workflow depending on your inputs.

For above example :

1. Mapper will read input data from HDFS file location from `FileInputFormat.addInputPath` API. Mapper is set by below line

   ```
   job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
   ```
2. Combiner, which is a mini reducer will run on Mapper output. It will reduce network IO by combining output of Mappers.

   ```
   job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
   ```
3. Reducer is set by below API.

   ```
   job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
   ```

***Mapper***

Mapper maps input key/value pairs to a set of intermediate key/value pairs. The Hadoop MapReduce framework spawns one map task for each InputSplit generated by the InputFormat for the job.

***Reducer***

Reducer reduces a set of intermediate values which share a key to a smaller set of values.

***Combiner:***

Users can optionally specify a combiner, via `Job.setCombinerClass(Class),` to perform local aggregation of the intermediate outputs, which helps to cut down the amount of data transferred from the Mapper to the Reducer.